# Count number of posts in child custom taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress

i have this code:

```
 <?php
$taxonomyName = "free";
$terms = get_terms($taxonomyName,array('parent' => 0));
foreach($terms as $term) {
    $term_children = get_term_children($term->term_id,$taxonomyName);
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($term_children as $term_child_id) {
        $term_child = get_term_by('id',$term_child_id,$taxonomyName);
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term_child->term_id, $taxonomyName ) . '">' . $taxtitle . ' ' . $term_child->name . '</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
?>
```

I want to count posts from each child taxonomy of this parent taxonomy.

I want to result something like this:

```
echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term_child->term_id, $taxonomyName ) . '">' . $taxtitle . ' ' . $term_child->name . '</a> (COUNT - Episodes)</li>';
```

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

it should be fairly simple :

```
<?php
$taxonomyName = "free";
$terms = get_terms($taxonomyName,array('parent' => 0));
foreach($terms as $term) {
    $term_children = get_term_children($term->term_id,$taxonomyName);
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($term_children as $term_child_id) {
        $term_child = get_term_by('id',$term_child_id,$taxonomyName);
        $q = new WP_Query(array(
            'nopaging' => true,
            'tax_query' => array(
              'taxonomy' => 'category',
              'field' => 'id',
              'terms' => $term_child_id,
              'include_children' => true,
          )));
         $count = $q->post_count;
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term_child->term_id, $taxonomyName ) . '">' . $taxtitle . ' ' . $term_child->name . '</a>(Season-'.$count.')</li>';          
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
?>
```

Comment: And I want to count each child category

Comment: ok what do you mean by child category ? $term_child_id ? I mean what is parent and child category above ?

Comment: I have this: Series (parent category) then Season 1, Season 2, etc. and I want to count Season 1 (COUNT here), Season 2 (count here), for each season. That's the code to show Seasons.

Comment: ok, that means $term = Series and $term_children = each Season  ?

Comment: I have to count $term_children by id...or something like that

Comment: 500 internal error. I think is because of this: $count = array

Comment: oh sorry my bad , please remove that , it was a typo. Also i am not sure what you are trying to count anymore because you said you want to count season ?

Comment: I want to count posts inside child taxonomy, this count me seasons, that I already have...

Comment: My bad, I didn't tell that I want to count posts of child taxonomy

Comment: Now count posts but from all child taxonomy, I want to count each child taxonomy.

Comment: change 'include_children' => false

Comment: Not working....to understand. I am in a parent taxonomy and in this page I listed children taxonomies. Now I want to count posts from each children taxonomy.

Comment: I am sorry but your explanation is not really clear, please update your question with meaning of following : $terms. $term_children and example result in plain text format(without code)

Comment: I don't know how to explain...that code I found it to show children taxonomies from a parent taxonomy...Now I try to count each children taxonomy....

Comment: Done: this was what I looking for: ' . $term_child->count . '

Comment: This is extremely expensive to run and totally bad for  SEO.